# Use Microsoft OpenXML to save excel file

Tags: excel, vb.net, spreadsheet, openxml

it's my first approach to openxml and I can't get it to work.
Hi want to create an xls file, write a value to specific cells and save it. This is the code I wrote for now, it creates the file but doesn't write any value at all. What I'm missing? Thanks

EDIT: as asked I addedd InsertCellInWorksheet function

```
    Sub Main()
        CreateSpreadsheetWorkbook("IMPOVO.XLS")
        Dim spreadSheet As SpreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open("IMPOVO.XLS", True)
        Using (spreadSheet)
    
            Dim worksheetPart As WorksheetPart = spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.WorksheetParts.First
            Dim cell As Cell = InsertCellInWorksheet("A", 1, worksheetPart)
    
            ' Set the value of cell A1.
            cell.CellValue = New CellValue("Hi World")
            cell.DataType = New EnumValue(Of CellValues)(CellValues.SharedString)
    
            ' Save the new worksheet.
            worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save()
            
        End Using
    End Sub
    
    Public Sub CreateSpreadsheetWorkbook(ByVal filepath As String)
        'Create a spreadsheet document by supplying the filepath.
        'By default, AutoSave = true, Editable = true, and Type = xlsx.
        Dim spreadsheetDocument As SpreadsheetDocument =
        SpreadsheetDocument.Create(filepath, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook)
        
        'Add a WorkbookPart to the document.
        Dim workbookpart As WorkbookPart = spreadsheetDocument.AddWorkbookPart
        workbookpart.Workbook = New Workbook
        
        'Add a WorksheetPart to the WorkbookPart.
        Dim worksheetPart As WorksheetPart = workbookpart.AddNewPart(Of WorksheetPart)()
        worksheetPart.Worksheet = New Worksheet(New SheetData())
        
        'Add Sheets to the Workbook.
        Dim sheets As Sheets = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild(Of Sheets)(New Sheets())
        
        'Append a new worksheet and associate it with the workbook.
        Dim sheet As Sheet = New Sheet
        sheet.Id = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart)
        sheet.SheetId = 1
        
        sheets.Append(sheet)
        
        workbookpart.Workbook.Save()
        
        'Close the document.
        spreadsheetDocument.Close()
    End Sub

Private Function InsertCellInWorksheet(ByVal columnName As String, ByVal rowIndex As UInteger, ByVal worksheetPart As WorksheetPart) As Cell
    Dim worksheet As Worksheet = worksheetPart.Worksheet
    Dim sheetData As SheetData = worksheet.GetFirstChild(Of SheetData)()
    Dim cellReference As String = (columnName + rowIndex.ToString())

    ' If the worksheet does not contain a row with the specified row index, insert one.
    Dim row As Row
    If (sheetData.Elements(Of Row).Where(Function(r) r.RowIndex.Value = rowIndex).Count() <> 0) Then
        row = sheetData.Elements(Of Row).Where(Function(r) r.RowIndex.Value = rowIndex).First()
    Else
        row = New Row()
        row.RowIndex = rowIndex
        sheetData.Append(row)
    End If

    ' If there is not a cell with the specified column name, insert one.  
    If (row.Elements(Of Cell).Where(Function(c) c.CellReference.Value = columnName + rowIndex.ToString()).Count() > 0) Then
        Return row.Elements(Of Cell).Where(Function(c) c.CellReference.Value = cellReference).First()
    Else
        ' Cells must be in sequential order according to CellReference. Determine where to insert the new cell.
        Dim refCell As Cell = Nothing
        For Each cell As Cell In row.Elements(Of Cell)()
            If (String.Compare(cell.CellReference.Value, cellReference, True) > 0) Then
                refCell = cell
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        Dim newCell As Cell = New Cell
        newCell.CellReference = cellReference

        row.InsertBefore(newCell, refCell)
        worksheet.Save()

        Return newCell
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: can you show your `InsertCellInWorksheet` routine?

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/working-with-the-shared-string-table. If you haven't already done so, you may consider downloading and installing the [Open XML SDK 2.5 Productivity Tool](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK#related-tools).

Answer (score 0):

This is just a suggestion, but try explicitly closing the document at the end of the Using block like your code does in the last instruction in the CreateSpreadsheetWorkbook() method to see if that resolved the issue.  You may also need to explicitly save the spreadsheet object at the end of the Using block.

Comment: spreadSheet.Close() after Using generate ad error System.ObjectDisposedException cannot access a deleted object

Comment: Allow me to clarify, when I wrote "at the end of the Using block" I meant place the save command as the last statement before you leave the Using block.  Let me know if this works for you.